# Getting the Total Value from Elements in a Map

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a method called `getValueForActivity` that needs to go through a `Map<String, Activity>` then for each `Activity` inside that map, go through a `Map<String, Expense>` and get the sum of all the expenses. It also needs to make sure that I'm inside one special type of user.

```
public ArrayList<Double> getValueForActivity(){
   ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
   for(Activity a:this.allActiv.values()){ //allActiv has all the activities on the system.
       double totalAct = 0;
       for(Expense e: this.expenses.values()){ //this.expenses has all the expenses on the system.
           if(this.userId.equals(e.getCustomerId())){ // this checks the user, doesn't matter
                if(e.getActivity().equals(a)){
                    totalAct += e.getExpenseValue();
                }
           }
       }
       list.add(totalAct);
   }
   return list;
}
```

At the moment this is printing an Array with the right values but with 1 error. It shifted the values to the right, so where the first should be 168.0 it's 0.0 and the second is 168.0, and so on.

What I'm looking for is to get a solution that not only allows me to print the total value for each `Activity` but that also prints the name of the activity before the respective total value. The method to get the `Activity` name is just `getName()`. The `ArrayList` is only allowing me to either have the value or the `Activity`.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for debugging tips.

Comment: Probably because your first Activity is not for that customer or an expense for that activity. You are always adding to the list regardless. Try putting the `list.add()` call in the inner most `if` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return a map of values with the activity name as key:

```
public Map<String, Double> getValueForActivity() {
    return this.allActiv.values()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Activity::getName, this::sumExpenses));
}

private double sumExpenses(Activity activity) {
    return this.expenses.values()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> this.userId.equals(e.getCustomerId()))
            .filter(e -> e.getActivity().equals(activity))
            .mapToDouble(Expense::getExpenseValue)
            .sum();
}
```

Comment: It is compiling but I'm not being able to print it on the screen. I already have a very long main but basicly the class that holds the main is called JavaFactura where i initialize it as: JavaExpense jf = new  JavaExpense();  After that i have something like System.out.println(jf.getValueForActivity().toString());

Comment: I can't help you unless you describe the problem more clearly.

Comment: Yes sorry i accidently pressed enter before finishing. Was trying to go into a new line.

Comment: So... what's the problem?

Comment: I'm not being able to print it out on my main... I created an instance of the class where main is with: JavaExpense je = new JavaExpense(); Then i did System.out.println(je.getValueForActivity().toString()); but it doesnt print anything.

Comment: What does "I'm not being able to print it out" mean? Is it printing anything? Does your screen go dark? Does your computer blow up? Help me help you.

Comment: Impossible that it prints nothing. You're leaving something out.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I already have 3 types of users where each has like 10 cases for different requirements so it's a mess. Was calling the method on the wrong case. Thank you very much!